# How to use a Function<T, R> as parameter in method

Tags: java, methods, lambda, comparable, method-reference

I'm learning Java lambdas for school, and I am stuck for a couple of days now.

### Background

I have a list of pumps which I have to sort out on power, last revision, …
I already wrote a `Comparator` that's returning a `List<Pump>`:

```java
class PowerComparator implements Comparator<Pomp> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pump pump1 , Pump pump2) {
        return Double.compare(pump1.getPower(), pump2.getPower());
    }
}
```

I have to write one function that's returning a `List<Pump>` that can returning a sorted list (power, revision, ...) using a lambda.

The method signature is:

```java
public List<Pump> sortedBy(Function<Pump, Comparable<Pump>> function)
```

I know that the `Function` interface is returning a `Comparator`, but I don't know how to use the function in it.

Below is what I already found (it's not correct). I am really stuck here.

```java
public List<Pump> sortedBy(Function<Pump, Comparable<Pump>> function){
    List<Pump> sortBy = new ArrayList<Pump>(pumps);
    function.apply((Pump) ->Comparator.comparing(pumps::comparator));
    Collections.sort(sortBy, Comparator.comparing(function.apply(pumps);
    return sortBy;
}
```

### Additional info (in dutch)

```
public class Data {

    private static List<Pomp> data;

    public static List<Pomp> getData() {
        data = new ArrayList<>();

        data.add(new Pomp("J6706A", 100.0, 2, Aandrijving.TURBINE, LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 10), true, 500.0, "Slurry pomp"));
        data.add(new Pomp("J6707A", 55.5, 1, Aandrijving.MOTOR, LocalDate.of(2022, 2, 10), false, 500.0, "Clarified pomp"));
        data.add(new Pomp("J6706B", 100.0, 2, Aandrijving.TURBINE, LocalDate.of(2022, 3, 10), true, 500.0, "Slurry pomp"));
        data.add(new Pomp("J6706C", 100.0, 2, Aandrijving.TURBINE, LocalDate.of(2022, 4, 10), true, 500.0, "Slurry pomp"));
        data.add(new Pomp("J6705A", 62, 1, Aandrijving.MOTOR, LocalDate.of(2022, 5, 10), false, 250, "Voedings pomp"));
        data.add(new Pomp("J6705B", 35, 2, Aandrijving.TURBINE, LocalDate.of(2022, 6, 10), false, 150, "Voedings pomp"));
        data.add(new Pomp("J6708B", 100.0, 2, Aandrijving.TURBINE, LocalDate.of(2022, 7, 10), false, 300, "HCO circ pomp"));

        return data;
    }

}

public class Pompen {
    private TreeSet<Pomp> pompen = new TreeSet<>();
    public void add(Pomp pomp) {
        pompen.add(pomp);
    }
 class VermogenComparator implements Comparator<Pomp> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pomp pomp1 , Pomp pomp2) {
            return Double.compare(pomp1.getVermogen(), pomp2.getVermogen());
        }
    }
    class RevisieComparator implements Comparator<Pomp> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pomp pomp1 , Pomp pomp2) {
            return pomp1.getLaatsteRevisie().compareTo(pomp2.getLaatsteRevisie());
        }
    }
    class Zelfontbranding implements Comparator<Pomp> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pomp pomp1 , Pomp pomp2) {
            return Boolean.compare(pomp1.getBovenZelfOntbranding(), pomp2.getBovenZelfOntbranding());
        }
    }
```

Comment: So `List<Pump> sortedBy(Function<Pump, Comparable<Pump>> function)` is dictated by your instructor and you can't change that signature? It doesn't make a lot of sense. `Function<Pump, Comparator<Pump>>` is a function that converts one pump into a rule for sorting any pumps. In addition, it's totally unclear where your `sortBy()` method is going to obtain all the `Pump` objects to put in the list.

Comment: It is indeed dictated by the instructor. I have a Pump List which contains the pumps. This is a TreeMap. The Function determine the sorting criterium from the base class (Power, LastRevison, ...) I have to test with following code: System.out.println("\nPumps sorted on power:");
for (Pump pump: Pumps.sortedBy(Pump::getName)) {
 System.out.println(pump);
}

Comment: Did the instructor provide any additional information that would address those issues? Normally, a `Comparator` doesn't have any state, or require any information for construction. There definitely are exceptions, but they would require some explanation as they wouldn't be obvious. So I'm puzzled about what to use as the `Pump` argument to the function when you obtain the `Comparator`.

Comment: @S.Cl *"dictated by the instructor"* -  you mean such type of function `Function<Pump, Comparable<Pump>>` us specified in your assignment? Can you provide the text of your assignment (the part related to this problem)?

Comment: Extra info <\n> The Function determine the sorting criterium from the base class (Power, LastRevison, ...) I have to test with following code: <\n> System.out.println("\nPumps sorted on power:");<\n>
for (Pump pump: Pumps.sortedBy(Pump::getName)) {<\n>
 System.out.println(pump);<\n>
}<\n> I've found something on Higher Order Functions. Trying to puth the pieces together. <\n> I think I've have to write a method that sort the list given the lambda syntax (criterium). So with one method I can sort the List different ways using different Lambda. I hope I clarified more.

Comment: @S.Cl *"a method that sort the list"* - so where this **list** that needs to be sorted resides? It's not passed into the method, or it should be... If not then there's an instance field (in the `Pumps`?) since the method is not `static`. Please reflect all relevant information **in your question** (not in the comments). Provide the code of your `Pump` and `Pumps` classes (only methods/fields relevant to the problem).

Comment: I've added additional info. It is (however) in Dutch. Thx in advanced.

Comment: What doesn't make sense is `Comparable<Pump>`. There are factory methods in `Comparator` that require a `keyExtractor`; given an object, the key extractor can choose a property to use as a key for sorting. This is what `Pump::getName` is doing. However, `Pump::getName` returns a `String`, not a `Pump`. The second generic type parameter of `Function` needs to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your example using `sortBy(Pump::getName)`, I believe that the intent here is to use the [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) factory to create a comparator that extracts a sort key from each object. However, this requires some changes to the generic types used in the prescribed method signature. Working code would look something like this:

```java
public <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<Pomp> sortedBy(Function<Pomp, ? extends U> toKey) {
    List<Pomp> sorted = new ArrayList<>(pompen);
    sorted.sort(Comparator.comparing(toKey));
    return sorted;
}
```

This will accept lambdas like `Pomp::getNaam` as long as the indicated property is `Comparable`:

```java
System.out.println("Pumps sorted on power:");
pompen.sortedBy(Pomp::getVermogen).forEach(System.out::println);
```

A better design would be to pass a `Comparator`; while it's a tiny bit more work for the caller, it gives them full control over the sorting. For example, they can specify a secondary sort key, or reverse the order. Or one could go another step further and simply return a copy of the pumps collection as a list and let the caller do whatever they wish with it.

---

If permitted, you could change the API to this:

```java
public List<Pomp> sortedBy(Comparator<? super Pomp> order) {
    List<Pomp> sorted = new ArrayList<>(pompen);
    sorted.sort(order);
    return sorted;
}
```

The caller would then be responsible for creating a `Comparator` that meets their need:

```java
/* Like this: */
List<Pomp> sortedByName = pompen.sortedBy(Comparator.comparing(Pomp::getNaam));
/* Or this: */
List<Pomp> pumpsDescendingPower = 
  pompen.sortedBy(Comparator.comparing(Pomp::getVermogen).reversed());
```

This approach is more idiomatic for Java.

Comment: It worked! I am figuring out what is going on in the method signature. I think: before the List<Pomp>: A class U that extends a Comparable interface of type unknown that is a subclass from U. After the List<Pomp> The function get's a Pomp as first parameter and returning an unknown class that's derived from class U. The toKey is the lamba function that you can pass when you are calling the method. How would you pass a Comparator? Like you said, this will be more logical.

Comment: @S.Cl I added an example using a `Comparator` directly.